# Related to java swings

Tags: java, swing

Need help!

In java swing, how can I jump back(open up) the hidden form from which the previous form had been generated?

Elaborating -> I made an object of form2 in form1, hid the 1st form and displayed the 2nd one. Now after a while I have to hide the form2 and open the original form1. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly are `form2` and `form1`?

Comment: Form1 is a class in which I made an object of Form2 on a button click. I used setVisible to hide Form1 and then open Form2. Now Form2 is visible. Then on a button click on Form2, I need to dispose Form2 and unhide Form1. I don't know any function to unhide Form2, neither do I want to create a new object of Form1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `form.setVisible(true) and form.setVisible(false)`

In form1 you'll put this under the button

```
form2 f2 = new form2(this);
```

In form2 you'll do this

```
f1.setVisible(false);
```

then when you go back

```
f1.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

Comment: ...but you will probably have to rerender?

Comment: I cannot do that because I don't want to create an object of Form1 in Form2. I need to unhide Form1 from Form2

Comment: You are going to have to create an object of Form1 in Form2 if you want to interact with it.

Comment: But wouldn't I lose the original Form1 and it's values then?

Comment: @Snehil_V127 See the changes in my answer, f1 is defined in the constructor of form2

Comment: @user1896006 I got it now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a really good reason to do something like this, then don't.

Instead, use a `CardLayout` which will allow you to move back and forward and set the currently active view at your hearts content

Check out [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) for more details